# Map annotated as "Lazy" not updated after adding entries

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I've the following Entity:

```
   class User {
    ..
    ...
    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "id.uKey")
    @MapKey(name="id.achieveId")
    private Map<Integer, Achievement> achievements;
    ..
    ..
}
```

at some point I call:
    Hibernate.Initialize();

and this map is filled with entries from DB.

when the app continues I save new entries into the DB table.

and then I try to access the map but it doesn't contain the new entries.

Is there a way to make it aware that it needs to re-select the DB table?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I add new entries like this:

```
public void save() {
    ..
    tx = dbs.beginTransaction();

    Achievement ua = new Achievement(key, id);
    dbs.save(ua);

    tx.commit();
}
```

Comment: Just query for the newest data. Implementing something like a data stream could be error-prone.

Comment: Is there a way to make it "aware" of the changes?

Comment: You want it to be Lazy, and then your problem is, that is Lazy?

Comment: Not sure about that, lazy means it was queried only when asked, but it doesn't mean it cannot be queried again.

Comment: You have cascading on that map, so simply persist new achievements by adding them into the map and letting hibernate do its auto-magic. That way you prevent wanting Hibernate to become a complicated threaded database polling engine.

Comment: After I add them to the map, do I need to call any Hibernate method? such as update() or save() or anything like that?

Comment: Of course. There is also a documentation available: http://hibernate.org/orm/documentation/.

Answer (score 0):

After initializing your object, it resides in the hibernate session and this session is not designed to be updated by changes from the underlying database. Just reload the object from the database, but remove it from the session before doing so.

But maybe, what you really want is to modify the map contained in your object. That would be the OOP way. After that you could persist the entire object with Hibernate.